# How to read html table as dataframe (urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>)?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would appreciate if you could let me know how to convert a html table into a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html('https://www.iasplus.com/en/resources/ifrs-topics/use-of-ifrs', header = None)
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\t\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/t/Downloads/hyperopt12.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/t/Downloads/hyperopt12.py", line 12, in <module>
    df = pd.read_html('https://www.iasplus.com/en/resources/ifrs-topics/use-of-ifrs', header = None)
  File "C:\Users\t\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1094, in read_html
    displayed_only=displayed_only)
  File "C:\Users\t\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 916, in _parse
    raise_with_traceback(retained)
  File "C:\Users\t\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 420, in raise_with_traceback
    raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the pandas version? `pd.__version__` ?

Comment: @anky_91 Thanks. It is 0.24.0. It could read this page: http://www.espn.com/nhl/statistics/player/_/stat/points/sort/points/year/2015/seasontype/2

Comment: @anky_91 I could read the link provided in the last comment but I'm not able to read the link provided in the question.

Comment: cannot reproduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the right table on the page to read. read_html returns a list of dataframe objects. See the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.read_html.html).

```
import pandas as pd
tables = pd.read_html('https://www.iasplus.com/en/resources/ifrs-topics/use-of-ifrs', header = None)
df = tables[2]
df
```

Comment: Thanks. the same error:
`tables = pd.read_html('https://www.iasplus.com/en/resources/ifrs-topics/use-of-ifrs', header = None)
  File "C:\Users\t\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1094, in read_html
    displayed_only=displayed_only)
  File "C:\Users\t\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 916, in _parse
    raise_with_traceback(retained)
  File "C:\Users\t\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 420, in raise_with_traceback
    raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>`

Comment: This is working for me in Jupyter Notebook. I'm unable to reproduce your error. Sorry. Maybe this article will be useful. <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28376506/urllib-https-request-urlopen-error-unknown-url-type-https>

Comment: Thanks. I also tried it in R. l was not able to read it in R too. Again, the link provided in the comment section could be read in R too.

Comment: `> library(XML)
> library(RCurl)
> library(rlist)
> theurl <- getURL("https://www.iasplus.com/en/resources/ifrs-topics/use-of-ifrs",.opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE) )
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
> tables <- readHTMLTable(theurl)
Error in readHTMLTable(theurl) : object 'theurl' not found
> tables <- list.clean(tables, fun = is.null, recursive = FALSE)
Error in list.clean(tables, fun = is.null, recursive = FALSE) : 
  object 'tables' not found`

Comment: `> n.rows <- unlist(lapply(tables, function(t) dim(t)[1]))
Error in lapply(tables, function(t) dim(t)[1]) : 
  object 'tables' not found
> tables[[which.max(n.rows)]]
Error: object 'tables' not found`

Comment: There was a problem with my Pycharm installation. However, I accepted your answer. Thanks.