# Having "urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>" error when trying to automate script, but works fine running inside Spyder

Tags: python, urllib

So I have a script that reads tables off certain websites.

When I run this script inside Python IDE, it works perfectly. If I try to run it as a batch file independently, it doesn't work. It reflects the following error: 
urllib.error.URLError:

Any ideas as to what might cause it? My script are really short:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Aug 18 20:24:04 2019

@author: blueb
"""
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dfs = pd.read_html("https://www.nea.gov.sg/dengue-zika/dengue/dengue-clusters")
count = 0
for df in dfs:
    count += 1
    print(df.head())

clusters_info = dfs[1]
clusters_info.to_csv('clusters.csv')


dls = "https://www.moh.gov.sg/docs/librariesprovider5/diseases-updates/weekly-infectious-bulletin_caseswk32y2019.xlsx?sfvrsn=cceaba67_0"
resp = requests.get(dls)

output = open('denguetrends.xlsx', 'wb')
output.write(resp.content)
output.close()

trends = pd.read_excel('denguetrends.xlsx')
trends.to_csv('denguetrends.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround use `http` if this page supports it. Real issue is the Python installation in the environment [broken `SSL`]:

[urllib HTTPS request: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28376506/urllib-https-request-urlopen-error-unknown-url-type-https)

Did you build the Python environment where this is happening? or was it pre-packaged?.

```
>>> import ssl
ImportError: No module named ssl
```

In any case, the Python interpreter that your `Spyder` installation is using, wasn't compiled with proper `SSL` support, or is not compatible with your system's `SSL`. Make sure you install `SSL` before installing `Spyder`. These are some resources that can help you:

- https://superuser.com/questions/1346141/how-to-link-python-to-the-manually-compiled-openssl-rather-than-the-systems-one

  [Building Python with SSL support in non-standard location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937337/building-python-with-ssl-support-in-non-standard-location)

  https://techglimpse.com/install-python-openssl-support-tutorial/

Comment: Using "http" in the url didn't cause it. The same issue was returned, so it looks like the url is automatically being redirected. Is there anything else you might suggest? i can't really make sense of the link.

Comment: I was afraid you were going to be redirected to `https` because most site do that now. Let me expand the answer a bit.