# Problem connecting to a postgresql database

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

I'm trying to read sheets and insert them into postgresql to make the staging tables in my etl_table.

The function was working, but now I'm getting a error.  I don't know what my problem is:

```py
      main.ipynb
        db_session = database_handler.create_connection('config.json')
        data_handler.read_dataset_create_tables_and_insert_data(db_session)
        ERROR:root:An error occurred: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
        ERROR:root:An error occurred: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
        ERROR:root:An error occurred: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
        ERROR:root:An error occurred: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
        ERROR:root:An error occurred: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
        ERROR:root:An error occurred: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
        ERROR:root:An error occurred: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
        ERROR:root:An error occurred: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
        ERROR:root:An error occurred: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
        ERROR:root:An error occurred: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
        ERROR:root:An error occurred: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
        ERROR:root:An error occurred: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
        2023-11-28 00:50:23.483310 - Failed to connect to database (database_handler.py) ##### <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
        2023-11-28 00:50:23.485303 - Failed to connect to database (database_handler.py) ##### <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
```

I'm using this code:

```py
     def read_sheet_as_dataframe(sheet_info):
        file_type = sheet_info["type"]
        file_config_parameter = sheet_info["config"]
        sheet_name = sheet_info["sheet_name"]
    
        df = data_handler.read_data_as_dataframe(file_type, file_config_parameter)
        return df, sheet_name
    
    def read_dataset_create_tables_and_insert_data(db_session):
        sheets_info = [
            {"type": lookups.FileType.CSV, "config": 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18GUCOh6BzZ6eLeM1fbLGrnPpW2DeUUal-jqci93w6R8/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=countries', "sheet_name": "countries"},
            {"type": lookups.FileType.CSV, "config": 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18GUCOh6BzZ6eLeM1fbLGrnPpW2DeUUal-jqci93w6R8/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=avg_temperature', "sheet_name": "avg_temperature"},
            {"type": lookups.FileType.CSV, "config": 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18GUCOh6BzZ6eLeM1fbLGrnPpW2DeUUal-jqci93w6R8/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=prevalence_of_undernourishment', "sheet_name": "prevalence_of_undernourishment"},
            {"type": lookups.FileType.CSV, "config": 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18GUCOh6BzZ6eLeM1fbLGrnPpW2DeUUal-jqci93w6R8/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=disaster_types', "sheet_name": "disaster_types"},
            {"type": lookups.FileType.CSV, "config": 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18GUCOh6BzZ6eLeM1fbLGrnPpW2DeUUal-jqci93w6R8/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=gdp', "sheet_name": "gdp"},
            {"type": lookups.FileType.CSV, "config": 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18GUCOh6BzZ6eLeM1fbLGrnPpW2DeUUal-jqci93w6R8/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=world_population', "sheet_name": "world_population"},
            {"type": lookups.FileType.CSV, "config": 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18GUCOh6BzZ6eLeM1fbLGrnPpW2DeUUal-jqci93w6R8/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=natural_disasters', "sheet_name": "natural_disasters"},
            {"type": lookups.FileType.CSV, "config": 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18GUCOh6BzZ6eLeM1fbLGrnPpW2DeUUal-jqci93w6R8/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=disaster_magnitude', "sheet_name": "disaster_magnitude"},
            {"type": lookups.FileType.CSV, "config": 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18GUCOh6BzZ6eLeM1fbLGrnPpW2DeUUal-jqci93w6R8/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=worldcities', "sheet_name": "worldcities"},
            {"type": lookups.FileType.CSV, "config": 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18GUCOh6BzZ6eLeM1fbLGrnPpW2DeUUal-jqci93w6R8/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=share_without_improved_water', "sheet_name": "share_without_improved_water"},
            {"type": lookups.FileType.CSV, "config": 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18GUCOh6BzZ6eLeM1fbLGrnPpW2DeUUal-jqci93w6R8/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=magnitude_scale', "sheet_name": "magnitude_scale"},
            {"type": lookups.FileType.CSV, "config": 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18GUCOh6BzZ6eLeM1fbLGrnPpW2DeUUal-jqci93w6R8/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=valuable_country_data', "sheet_name": "valuable_country_data"},
    
    
        ]
    
        for sheet_info in sheets_info:
            df, sheet_name = read_sheet_as_dataframe(sheet_info)
            create_table_and_insert_data(db_session, df, sheet_name)
```

so basically i'm trying to read my sheets and insert them in the database it was working up until i got this error , if anyone has a fix please  i would really appreciate it . Thank you by advance !

and here is the config.json

```
{
    "db_host" : "localhost",
    "db_name" : "Pluto",
    "db_user" : "postgres",
    "db_pass" : "Laptop2018",
    "port_id" : "5433",


    "countries": "kaggle",
    "share_without_improved_water": "kaggle",
    "avg_temperature": "kaggle",
    "worldcities": "Simplemaps",
    "gdp": "UNdata",
    "prevalence_of_undernourishment": "OurWorldInData",
    "natural_disasters": "emdat",
    "valuable_country_data": "OECD",
    "world_population":"kaggle",
    "disaster_types":"manual",
    "disaster_magnitude":"manual",
    "magnitude_scale":"manual"
    
}
```

and this is how i create the connection :

```
def create_connection(config_file):
    db_session = None
    try:
        config_data = file_handler.read_config(config_file)

        if config_data is not None:
            db_host = config_data.get("db_host")
            db_name = config_data.get("db_name")
            db_user = config_data.get("db_user")
            db_pass = config_data.get("db_pass")
            db_port = config_data.get("port_id")

            if db_host and db_name and db_user and db_pass:
                db_session = psycopg2.connect(
                    host=db_host,
                    database=db_name,
                    user=db_user,
                    password=db_pass,
                    port=db_port
                )
            else:
                print("Missing database connection parameters in the config file.")
        else:
            print("Failed to read the configuration file.")
    except Exception as error:
        prefix = lookups.ErrorHandling.DB_CONNECTION_ERROR.value
        suffix = str(error)
        print_error_console(suffix, prefix)
        log_error(f'An error occurred: {str(error)}')

    finally:
        return db_session
```

Comment: What's the content of `config.json`?. Did you check your URI matches with what [postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING-URIS) says?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you create a clean Python environment because this could be related to SSL installation (see relevant [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57560615/having-urllib-error-urlerror-urlopen-error-unknown-url-type-https-error-wh)).

It would also help answering your question if you include additional details how you create the connection.

Comment: i have added the code of config and how i create the connection

Comment: Have you tried if the connection works at all? Also, how do you install psycopg2?