# django urllib HTTPS request: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>

Tags: python, django

i get error when using urllib

python 2.6
django 1.4.1

when i using python

```
> import ssl
```

get

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/xxx/lib/python2.6/ssl.py", line 60, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: libssl.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

i have openssl installed

```
openssl version -v
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
```

Comment: Neither Python 2.6 or Django 1.4.x are supported any longer. I would highly recommend using a current version, as neither is receiving security updates. In regards to your question, I use the `requests` package for all of my HTTP needs rather than Python's built-ins: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: Also see [urllib HTTPS request: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28376506/608639), [urllib cannot read https](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27208131/608639), [urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: 'https>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27115803/608639), [urllib HTTPS request: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44750732/608639), etc.