# An unexpected URLError is raised when I run my compiled Python script

Tags: python, url, beautifulsoup, urllib, cx-freeze

I've been working on a web scraping program. It works fine when I run it in the Pycharm IDE. However, when compiled with cx_Freeze, I get the error:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
```

Here is the part of my code that concerns the url processing:

```
url = f"https://op.gg/summoner/userName={f_username}"
        page_html = urlopen(url)
        page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_html, features="html.parser")
```

I've searched the internet and I've found that the error may be due to a single-quote somewhere. However:

- I can run it in an IDE
- When I print my url, it is perfectly fine (no single-quote).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Strange. What happens when you run it with Python in your terminal? I suppose replacing your first line with this makes no difference: `url = urllib.parse.urljoin("https://op.gg/summoner/", urllib.parse.urlencode({"userName": f_username}))`

Comment: When run in the terminal, no error is raised. It works as it should.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115803/urllib-error-urlerror-urlopen-error-unknown-url-type-https

Comment: Wow, should have looked for dupes first. Thanks!

Comment: So, what was the problem in the end? Did using `urlencode` fix it?

Comment: Well, the error is gone and I can run the compiled script! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says : "unknown url type: https",
so the problem is that HTTPS is not supported.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html says :
"HTTPS support is only available if Python was compiled with SSL support (through the ssl module)."